# How to rotate Shipping Label image retrieved from Carrier while confirming Shipment in Acumatica?

Tags: c#, acumatica, acumatica-kb

We are using custom Packing Slip report in Acumatica which works with all different type of carriers (UPS, FedEx, USPS Etc. ) and requires Shipping Label image without any rotation.

Shipping Label image retrieved via Stamps.com and FedEx is without any rotation but shipping label image via UPS carrier integration is 270 degree rotated clockwise out-of-box and that doesn’t fit well in designated area (adhesive) of the stationary/Report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s no option with UPS Shipping Label API to specify rotation degree for shipping label image. We will be solving this via customization for `ShipmentEntry` graph/BLC working with `Shipment Entry screen (SO302000)`.

There won’t be any change in current workflow (End-user perspective). When Shipment is confirmed in Acumatica, label is generated and retrieved from UPS, during this process our customization will rotate retrieved label (only if Ship-Via on Shipment is working with UPS Plug-in and Label Format is GIF) clockwise 90 degree. This UPS label will be aligned with label generated via other Plug-ins (FedEx and Stamps.com). And no adjustment will be needed at Report level.

Shipping Label is generated via `ShipPackages` virtual method in `ShipmentEntry` Graph/BLC. So, we will be overriding `ShipPackages` virtual method in Graph/BLC Extension of the `ShipmentEntry` Graph/BLC.

```cs
public class SOShipmentEntryRotateGIFLabelExt : PXGraphExtension<SOShipmentEntry>
{
     public delegate void ShipPackagesBaseDelegate(SOShipment shiporder);

     [PXOverride]
     public void ShipPackages(SOShipment shiporder, ShipPackagesBaseDelegate BaseInvoke)
     {
         //Custom code to rotate image if carrier is UPS and label format is GIF                 
         //Invoke base method 
         BaseInvoke(shiporder);
     }
}
```

File attachment in Acumatica is performed via `UploadFileMaintenance` Graph/BLC.
We will extend the logic by adding the `RowInserted` event handler for the `UploadFileRevision` DAC to the `UploadFileMaintenance` graph.

Because the `UploadFileMaintenance` BLC instance is created within `ShipPackages` and is not available until it is executed, we will add a delegate to the static `InstanceCreated` collection of the `PXGraph` class.

And Within the delegate, which executes when the `UploadFileMaintenance` BLC instance is initialized, we will add an event handler to the `RowInserted` collection of the `UploadFileMaintenance` Graph/BLC instance.

```cs
public class SOShipmentEntryRotateGIFLabelExt : PXGraphExtension<SOShipmentEntry>
{
    public delegate void ShipPackagesBaseDelegate(SOShipment shiporder);

    [PXOverride]
    public void ShipPackages(SOShipment shiporder, ShipPackagesBaseDelegate BaseInvoke)
    {
        #region Custom-code-to-rotate-retrieved-Label

        PXGraph.InstanceCreated.AddHandler<UploadFileMaintenance>((fileGraph) =>
        {
            fileGraph.RowInserted.AddHandler<UploadFileRevision>((sender, e) =>
            {
                UploadFileRevision fileData = (UploadFileRevision)e.Row;
            });
        });

        #endregion
        //Invoke base method 
        BaseInvoke(shiporder);
    }
}
```

In the `RowInserted` event handler, we take the `UploadFileRevision` data record that is being processed and retrieve the shipping label image and rotate it.

And finally we invoke base method.

```cs
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.SO;
using PX.SM;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;

namespace PX.RotateUPSLabelImage.Ext
{
    public class SOShipmentEntryRotateGIFLabelExt : PXGraphExtension<SOShipmentEntry>
    {
        public delegate void ShipPackagesBaseDelegate(SOShipment shiporder);

        [PXOverride]
        public void ShipPackages(SOShipment shiporder, ShipPackagesBaseDelegate BaseInvoke)
        {
            #region Custom-code-to-rotate-retrieved-Label
            //Identify specified Ship-Via/Carrier Shipment is working with
            var carrier = Carrier.PK.Find(Base, shiporder.ShipVia);
            //If specified Ship-Via/Carrier is API/Plug-In based
            if (carrier?.IsExternal == true)
            {
                //Identify Connected Carrier Plug-In 
                var plugin = CarrierPlugin.PK.Find(Base, carrier.CarrierPluginID);
                //If Plug-In is working with UPS
                if (plugin?.PluginTypeName?.Trim() == typeof(PX.UpsCarrier.UpsCarrier).FullName)
                {
                    PXGraph.InstanceCreated.AddHandler<UploadFileMaintenance>((fileGraph) =>
                    {
                        fileGraph.RowInserted.AddHandler<UploadFileRevision>((sender, e) =>
                        {
                            UploadFile fileInfo = (UploadFile)sender.Graph.Caches<UploadFile>()?.Current;
                            if (fileInfo != null)
                            {
                                if (fileInfo.Name.StartsWith("Label #") && (fileInfo.Extansion.ToUpper() == "GIF"))
                                {
                                    UploadFileRevision fileData = (UploadFileRevision)e.Row;
                                    using (MemoryStream fileMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(fileData?.Data))
                                    {
                                        Image labelImage = Image.FromStream(fileMemoryStream);
                                        if (labelImage != null)
                                        {
                                            labelImage.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
                                            ImageConverter imgConverter = new ImageConverter();
                                            fileData.Data = (byte[])imgConverter.ConvertTo(labelImage, typeof(byte[]));
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
            #endregion
            //Invoke base method 
            BaseInvoke(shiporder);
        }
    }
}
```

[Download Acumatica Customization deployment package](https://github.com/Acumatica/Acumatica-Rotate-UPS-Label)

Below help articles can be referred in Acumatica Customization Guide

[To Explore the C# Code of a BLC](https://help-2019r2.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=3aefb7f7-8213-449b-a4c6-2bf9a0d1d750)

[To Override a Virtual Method](https://help-2019r2.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=6fa2a444-17b4-42f9-9e6a-64e85167626a)